# How to hide action bar buttons in certain activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have 2 activity in my program MainActivity and SubActivity.  And I need some action bar buttons in SubActivity but not in MainActivity.  How can I hide them in MainActivity.

BUT I dont want to hide the actionbar in MainActivity (As I saw some questions here to hide whole actionbar)

Comment: use Custom Actionbar and custom button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch between Activities every time you enter one it's `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called. It  is where you inflate your menu. If you want to not have action bar buttons in MainActivity then inflate empty menu in it. In SubActivity inflate menu with action bar buttons.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.user.twoactivities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

SubActivity.javva

```
package com.example.user.twoactivities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SubActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SubActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.subactivity_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Go to SubActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_sub.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Go to MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
</menu>
```

subactivity_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Don't forget to add MainActivity and SubActivity to Manifest file.

Comment: Can u give me one example code. I am new to android pls

Answer (score 1):

In case you have your own custom ActionBar you can simply reference `MenuItem` and hide it when needed inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` as @michal.z mentioned.

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.idOfYourMenuItem);
item.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at Android, too. Other answers shown are probably correct, and, maybe I'm missing something... but, my method has been to simply create a different menu for each activity in the XML editor of Android Studio (there's a menu folder under under res folder). Then, make sure you specify the right menu to be inflated, for each activity, in the onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

Answer (score 0):

go to AndroidManifest.xml and set the theme to every activity you want hide. Put this code in activity tag.

Code to hide the actionBar

> android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Code to show the actionBar

> android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"

here is the example

`

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
     >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

'